# Can I use a PlayStation 3 or 4 controller with a 4th gen AppleTV?

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, games, remote-control

Does anyone have experience pairing and using an official Sony PlayStation 3 or 4 controller with the 4th gen Apple TV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use Made For iPhone (MFi) controllers with the Apple TV at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that for the iPhone, a PS 4 controller can be used on a jail-broken phone using an app called Controllers for All. I'm not aware of any other methods.

Under the assumption that the Apple TV is mostly an iOS device, and if a jailbreak for the new Apple TV is possible, then I'd expect the developer of Controllers for All to try to release a version for the Apple TV.

That said, I haven't seen any word from the developer (Ori Kadosh, @cjori) that he plans for an Apple TV release.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can buy a [SteelSeries Nimbus Wireless Gaming Controller](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJ162ZM/A/steelseries-nimbus-wireless-gaming-controller) for around $50 for the Apple TV (4th generation).

Comment: It's not made by Apple, merely sold through the Apple Store. [Though if it made it to the Apple Store it's probably a decent product.]

Comment: I have one. It works and is generally a pretty good controller.